# Javascript 2D Array Check Div Class

Tags: javascript, arrays, grid

I have created a simple Lights Out game using javascript. My grid is 10x10. The basic layout is one div for the entire board, each row has its own div and within that there are ten more divs with a class light. When the light is "on" the class is changed to light on and when its off the class is light off. Everything works perfectly but I'm trying to implement a function to check to see if all lights are off so it can notify the user that the game is over. I have no problem uploading my code but I was looking for basic syntax for this function. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

answering my own question. I used a jquery hasClass method that scans all divs for the light on class. Seems to work perfectly.

$("div").hasClass("light on")